# Using ISNULL does not produce the expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to concatenate several columns of a person's name into one column and ultimately into a temporary table. I am unable to get the `ISNULL` function to work correctly.

I have tried using `ISNULL` to effectively say "if this column is blank, then just ignore it". I've read about a command called `ISBLANK` but that doesn't seem to work on my version of SQL Server.

```
SELECT
    co.serialnumber, co.envelopesalutation, 
    co.title + ' ' + LEFT(co.firstname, 1) + ' ' + ISNULL(LEFT(co.otherinitial, 1), '') +
               ' ' + co.keyname + ' ' + ISNULL(co.POSTNOMINAL, '') [Correct]
INTO 
    TEMPENVSALUTATION
FROM
    contact co
WHERE
    co.contacttype = 'Individual' 
    AND co.title IN ('Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Miss', 'Mx', 'Dr')
```

I expect, for example, that someone with co.title of Mr, a co.firstname of Jon, no co.otherinitial a co.keyname of Smith and no co.postnominal to appear in the TEMPENVSALUTATION table as Mr J Smith

What I'm actually getting is only people who have a co.otherinitial appearing e.g. Mr S D Smith.

Comment: Can you give us an example of inputs-outputs?

Comment: Show sample data and  the expected result. No scalar function in the `select` clause can affect the number of rows returned.

Comment: I'm not a SQLServer expert but try `TRIM(LEFT(ISNULL(co.otherinitial, ' '), 1))` instead of `ISNULL(LEFT(co.otherinitial, 1), '')`

Comment: You are misunderstanding the results.  The only filters are the ones in the `where` clause and those do not (seem to) involve the initials.